# Laravel: how to access a file in the local disk? - File does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, phpexcel

I'm trying to edit an excel file after uploading it in laravel.
the file is uploaded to local disk, so no one can access it from the public.

**Filesystems.php**

```
'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app')
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('test',function()
{

    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(Storage::disk('local')->url('margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx'));
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
})->middleware('admin');
```

I keep getting error:

```
Could not open /storage/margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.
```

this works

```
     $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('..'.Storage::disk('local')->url('app/margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx'));
```

but it is annoying. I thought specifying 'root' => storage_path('app') in the filesystems.php means that Storage::disk('local') will be in the app directly

Comment: Do you have 0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx file in correct path?

Comment: you pass your file to storage/app but trying to get it from storage/margin try to add app/ inside your url function

Comment: Still the same error. but this works. '..' . Storage::disk('local')->url('app/margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx'). but it is annoying. I thought specifying 'root' => storage_path('app') in the filesystems.php means that Storage::disk('local') will be in the app directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [URL method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls) is used to get URL for the file (ie: something to access it from the browser). What you want to use id the `get()` method.

```
$contents = Storage::get(''margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx'');
```

That being said, there is still easier way to manipulate uploaded files with Laravel.

```
// this will take the uploaded file from the request
// and store it into `/storage/someFolder`
$path = $request->file('file')->store('someFolder');
```

You can then use the value returned to `$path` to access the file.

**EDIT**

After discussion below, it was decided by OP that, even if it's not the the perfect solution, he would use `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('..'.Storage::disk('local')->url($fileLocation));`.

Comment: Storage::get returns this error:   ErrorException in Excel2007.php line 234: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given. And I am using the "store" way to save the file but it returns this path: "margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx" which I am using in my code and it doesn't work. really annoying.

Comment: @medoampir can you confirm that there is indeed a file in `/storage/app/margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx' ?

Comment: @maedoampir Your question stated that you where getting error, and you where getting it because "url()" gets an URL, and not the path to the file. Using 'Sorage::get()' with the correct path (without having to specify 'app' in the path) seems like the right way to go, I'm not sure what you expect more at this point if it's only because you think the code looks ugly ;-)

Comment: I was just expecting after defining this part in the filesystems.php ('local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),) . To be able to use this part (Storage::disk('local')) as an instruction to laravel to get the file inside the app folder. why do I have to place this part '..' before Storage::disk? :(

Comment: You just said two comments up that using `Storage::get('margin/analyser/0IGkQ‌​QgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZF‌​UPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx‌​')` was working. And there is no ".." there?

Comment: sorry my bad, I copied the wrong code, please check the original post.

Comment: Buy why are you still using the "url" method? This is to get a URL for a file, not it's path. Unless I am mistaken, `PHPExcel_IOFactory::load` will want to access the file with the path, not an URL?

Comment: actually it doesn't return a url in my case, it returns this "../storage/app/margin/analyser/2KA8iXFeeBJH9xsziY7RSlkK4NnOtS6tBid6shPv.xlsx" . and "get" returns the file content not the path. that is why i'm confused the url is not actually returning a url. and please note that this file is in the local disk not the public, so there is no url.

Comment: Well, reading a bit more into this, it seems that it does returns a path with you use `url()` with the local storage! (The more you know!). That being said, it made me think: if you let the ".." to go up a level go and actually get the full path using the corresponding helper? See this code: https://paste.laravel.io/1Xylb

Comment: hilarious, this returns "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxx\storage\app/margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx"

Comment: I think if you use `$fullFilePath = realpath($fullFilePath)` with my example given on the pastebien, it might convert the path to a windows compatible one.

Comment: you know what, I'm gonna just assume that laravel is a kid and i'm the adult one, and just use this method. "     $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('..'.Storage::disk('local')->url('app/margin/analyser/0IGkQQgmGXkHrV9ISnBTrGyZFUPfjz3cWJbLGbDN.xlsx'));" thank you for your help. If you wish to edit your code and I will definitely mark it as the correct answer :)