# Laravel's UploadedFile store method's behavior doesn't correspond with Storage::url behavior

Tags: laravel, filesystems, storage

So I am having an UploadedFile I want to upload to specific disk 'local'.

```
// $storedFilePath == "kml/uploadedfile.xml";
$storedFilePath = $request->file->store("kml", "local");
```

The file is actually uploaded into storage/app/kml/uploadedfile.xml - that is CORRECT, following the config for local disk:

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

On the other hand, I need to get the full URL path (relative from project root) to this file. I tried

```
 Storage::disk("local")->url($storedFilePath);
```

But this gets me `/storage/kml/uploadedfile.xml` - note the path does miss app/ folder.

One line in Laravel's FilesystemAdapter.php that determines the path is here (function getLocalUrl):

```
    $path = '/storage/'.$path;
```

Given the fact that $path is starting with kml/ it perfectly makes sense that it doesn't work. My question is, why. Why are these not corresponding and how do I get the full internal (so not public) path?

Comment: For somebody wanting to close this question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274387/laravel-how-to-access-a-file-in-the-local-disk-file-does-not-exist) let me just tell you that the answer there is not actually telling me why would Laravel give the wrong path and HOW do i actually get the correct path without manually appending "app/" as it kills the whole purpose of using Storage disks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it was actually quite simple, yet I believe the documentation about this in Laravel is quite confusing. Laravel is just expecting everyone to have a symlink from public/storage into storage/app/public

They somehow even think that everyone using local disk and method url wants to know the public url, which is quite always true only for public disk.

config/filesystems.php

added 'url'

```
   'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'url' => storage_path('app')
    ],
```

Works correctly now